# Is there any mechanism where the kernel part of an OS in memory may also be swapped?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I'm recently learning the part of *I/O buffering* of operating system and according to the book I use,

> When a user process issues an I/O request, the OS assigns a buffer in the system portion of main memory to the operation.

I understand how this method is able to avoid the swapping problem in non-buffering situation. But is it assumed that the OS buffering created for the process will never be swapped out?

To extend my question, I was wondering if there is any mechanism where  the kernel portion of an OS in memory may also be swapped?

Comment: The term OS is very vague in this question. For example, do you include graphical interface as a part of OS? Do you include utilities?

Comment: @v010dya Yeah...I mean the kernel of the operating system. I'll update my question.

Comment: In the old times (mainframe era, long before Unix) even the OS-memory was classified into resident and non-resident classes

Comment: there is no swap of kernel this days so only time it swap to disk is when system reboot or shut down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common for operating systems to page out parts of the kernel. The kernel has to define what parts may be paged out and which may not be paged out. For example, typically, there will be separate memory allocators for paged pool and non-paged pool.

Note that on most processors the page table format is the same for system pages as for user pages, thus supporting paging of the kernel.

Determining what parts of the kernel may be paged out is part of the system design and is done up front. You cannot page out the system interrupt table. You can page out system service code for the most part. You cannot page out interrupt handling code for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is any mechanism where the kernel portion of an OS in memory

IIRC some old versions of AIX might have been able to swap (i.e. to paginate) some kernel code. And probably older OSes too (perhaps even Multics).

However, it practically is useless today, because the kernel memory is a tiny fraction of the RAM on current (desktop & server) computers. The total kernel memory is several dozens of megabytes only, while most computers have several dozens of gigabytes of RAM.

BTW, [microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) systems (e.g. GNU Hurd) can have server programs in paging processes.

See [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)